# Why are adverbs included in the form class? Do they change forms?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, class-based-usage

The word 'green' being an adjective has other forms such as greener and greenest. The form of the word changes and therefore it belongs to the form class. 
Could anyone give the explanation for the case of adverbs being included in the form class?
 Do they change form?

Thank you.

Comment: I presume that by the _form class_ you mean the class which includes words that can be inflected. Some adverbs are inflected in the comparative/superlative. For example: _You need to work *harder*.  She works *faster* than her brother_.

Comment: Thanks for the input. It is really useful.